How do I make this selection part of screen in flutter?
Screen
I wanted to create the options location 1 and location 2 just below the appbar
On presssing I want to change the contents below. Similar to the working of a nav bar.
Are there any widgets available to do this ?
I could use two text button and wrap it in a row and achieve this by adding actions to the on pressed part. But rather than that are there any better ways to do it ?

You can use Tabbar widget for this.

You can use Tabbar for this and for BottomNavigationBar you can use BottomNavigationBar.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Buddy simply learn about TabView and Utalize
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('TabView Example'),
    bottom: TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
        Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
        Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  body: TabBarView(
    children: [
      Center(child: Text('Content for Tab 1')),
      Center(child: Text('Content for Tab 2')),
      Center(child: Text('Content for Tab 3')),
    ],
  ),
)

